# Bash script does not recognize device id?

Tags: bash, shell

I've been working on a script that will run on startup but I am running into a problem. The script is meant to slow mouse acceleration because I use a gaming mouse and it's always too fast.

When I use xinput --list I get this output (out of many other lines):

> SteelSeries Sensei Raw Gaming Mouse       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]

When I open terminal and run this command, everything runs fine and my sensitivity is changed:

```
xinput --set-prop 10 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 2
```

However, when I put the above string in a shell.sh with 'eval' in the beginning, it prompts me the following error:

> property 'Device' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and
>   format

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you use `eval`?

Comment: A bad tutorial I assume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `eval`; put the command exactly as you used it from the terminal in your script.

The problem is that `eval` essentially reparses the string it receives, which results from joining the arguments arguments with whitespace. Your `eval` command is equivalent to

```
xinput --set-prop 10 Device Accel Constant Deceleration 2
```

You *could* use `eval` if you quoted the entire string:

```
eval 'xinput --set-prop 10 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 2'
```

but there is no reason to do so; just use

```
xinput --set-prop 10 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 2
```

Answer (score 1):

As said on other posts, you don't need to use eval. I would also add something else: you should use the name of the device, rather than the id number, because the id number can change if you add things to your computer (or for other more obscure reasons, too). I would recommend this:

```
xinput --set-prop "SteelSeries Sensei Raw Gaming Mouse" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 2
```

Comment: This would work perfectly if my mouse wasn't showing up 3 times in xinput --list with different id's. If I run a grep after the list command this is the output:

xinput --list | grep Steel #outputs the following

⎜   ↳ SteelSeries Sensei Raw Gaming Mouse      id=10 [slave  pointer  (2)]
    

⎜   ↳ SteelSeries Sensei Raw Gaming Mouse      id=12 [slave  pointer  (2)]


    ↳ SteelSeries Sensei Raw Gaming Mouse      id=11 [slave  keyboard (3)]

it uses id's 10 11 and 12 for some reason.

Comment: Interesting! I'd try it with the name anyway and see what happens.